# How to get all data from multiple tables linked by foreign keys with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm having trouble to fetch all data from the following database:

[image]

I created controllers for all of the entities shown above like this:

```
    // Retrieve entire DB
    AareonAPIDBEntities dbProducts = new AareonAPIDBEntities();

    // Get all customers
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("customer")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Default()
    {
        List<Customer> customers = dbProducts.Customers.ToList();
        return customers;
    }

    //Get customer by ID
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("customer/{id}")]
    public Customer getById(int id = -1)
    {
        Customer t = dbProducts.Customers
                               .Where(h => h.customerID == id)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
        return t;
    }
```

Now I'm having trouble finding out how to retrieve all of the database data linked by foreign keys in table `PropertyLeaseContract` by `customerID`. I'm trying to get a JSON response where I get the `customersID` and values, therein an array of objects from the linked `LeaseContract` and `Property`.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relations are properly set up in the DbContext Configuration and you have appropriate Navigation Properties in your Entity Classes it should work something like this:

```
public Customer getById(int id = -1)
{
    Customer t = dbProducts.Customers
            .Where(h => h.customerID == id)
            .Include(x => x.PropertyLeaseContracts)
              .ThenInclude(x => x.LeaseContract)
            .Include(x => x.PropertyLeaseContracts)
              .ThenInclude(x => x.Property)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    return t;
}
```

For that to work your Customer Class needs to have a Collection Property of PropertyLeaseContract and be setup as a OneToMany Relation.
And your PropertyLeaseContract class needs to have Properties of type LeaseContract and Property and also be setup correctly.

**EDIT:**
The above code works only in Entity Framework Core as mentioned by @TanvirArjel.
In Entity Framework Full code should look something like this:

```
public Customer getById(int id = -1)
{
    Customer t = dbProducts.Customers
            .Where(h => h.customerID == id)
            .Include(x => x.PropertyLeaseContracts.Select(plc => plc.LeaseContract))
            .Include(x => x.PropertyLeaseContracts.Select(plc => plc.Property))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    return t;
}
```

Comment: `.ThenInclude(x => x.LeaseContract)` is newly introduced in EF Core not in EF 6.x.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm getting the following error: "IQueryable<customer> does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type IQueryable<customer> could be found."

Comment: as @TanvirArjel mentioned this is only possible in Entity Framework Core. 
I will append the answer with code for Entity Framework full.